# concrete slab weight

Tags: concrete, slab

Can you please give me the weight of a concrete slab the measurement is 2.5 X 2.5 metres Thickness 8cm   This is for the purpose of disposing  this amount concrete to waste management (Council Tip)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your (apparent) second sentence isn't clear; what is this for? (And, depending on the substrate, 8cm is a very thin concrete slab, especially one that large.)

Answer (score 2):

Approximately 2,350 lbs or 1,065 kgs.

Source: http://www.calculator.net/concrete-calculator.html